# codeigniter authorization best workflow

Tags: codeigniter, session, permissions, authorization

I would like to know which is the best aproach to do the following. I have a codeignitor aplication and I need to display different views depending on the user permissions.

**User authentication:** the company I work uses CAS. No worries here. I just have the CAS library and the first thing the user does in order to access my application is to login through CAS. The CAS returns the username like this: "name.surname"

**User authorization:** We have a MySQL table with something like this:

**Permissions table:**

username | permission code

tim.cook | 1

adam.hook | 2

1 is **admin**
2 is **normal user**

I cannot change any of these (CAS for authentication nor table for roles) and I do not want to use a auth library for that. What would be the best approach for building my website? How about this:

1. User logs in and then I store his/her username to codeigniter session
2. Immediately look for the username in the permissions tables and store his/her role code (1 or 2) in the codeigniter session
3. Everytime there is a need to execute a function in a controller, check first if the session role can do that action or not.

Is there any tutorial, example or snipped of code so that I can see this in action?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it like that. In case a user permission can be changes you should also update the session permission value for critical functions.

You should also only store the hash of the password in the database. Maybe you can use the username as salt for the hashing.